# append id to actionlink jquery dialog

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc-4

This is what I'm looking to do
[image: the way I see it] 
I have a row of items that has an open button which should open a dialog that has that item inside of it, but I can't get the url to post correctly. 
In adding this diagram to this question I saw how stackoverflow pops up a dialog and that's exactly what I need to do. My problem is I need the url to be `/controller/action?id= (id being passed in)` but the url I get is `/controller/action?/7` or if i rewrite the action I get`/controller/action?/7` how to get rid of the slash or post it correctly?

ActionLink

```
       @Html.ActionLink("Open", "AddItems", new { id = item.ID }, new { @id =
      "Itemdialog" })
```

jQuery

```
  $('#dialog').dialog({
    autoOpen: false,
    width: 400,
    resizable: false,
    modal: true
});

$('#Itemdialog').on("click", function () {
    var url =  $(this).attr('href');
    $('#dialog').load(url, function () {
        $(this).dialog('open');
    });

    return false; 
});
```

Controller:

```
   public ActionResult AddItems(int id)
    {
        var TradeItem = from i in db.Items
                        where i.ID == id
                        select i;
        var results = TItem;


        return PartialView("_OpenItem", results); //need to open in dialog

    }
```

View

```
    @model IEnumerable<Item>

<table>
  <tr>
    <th>
         @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.ID)
    </th>
    <th>
        @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.user_id)
    </th>
    <th>
        @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.item_name)
    </th>
    <th>
        @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.item_description)
    </th>
    <th>
        @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.item_code)
    </th>
    <th>
        @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.dateAdded)
    </th>
    <th>
        @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.catId)
    </th>
    <th></th>
</tr>

@foreach (var item in Model) {

<tr>
    <td>
        @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.ID)
    </td>
    <td>
        @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.user_id)
    </td>
    <td>
        @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.item_name)
    </td>
    <td>
        @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.item_description)
    </td>
    <td>
        @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.item_code)
    </td>
    <td>
        @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.dateAdded)
    </td>
    <td>
        @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.catId)
    </td>

</tr>
}

  </table>
   @Html.ActionLink(send to db )
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could leave the `routeValues` blank, and simply append the query string to the end:

```
<a id="Itemdialog" href='@Url.Action("AddItems")?id=@item.ID'>Open</a>
```

I think that's a more straightforward way to set the query string -- using `routeValues` implies you want to construct the URL based on the route definitions.

Comment: `Open + ?id= + 1` this is the html. the `?id=` is not appending

Comment: @healix sorry.  I got the syntax wrong.  It should be like my edit, no spaces or quotes.  (and using `Url.Action` instead of ActionLink)

Comment: @healix finally got it now, I think -- just had to convert all the `ActionLink` stuff to a regular HTML tag.

Comment: I was just about to ask you about `@Url.Action` too. let me run it

Comment: That did it. I just need to re-wire my jQuery now because it's not firing. Thanks. Much Appreciated